# How to add bread crumbs in "1 Column Page" (Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, template, breadcrumbs

How I can add bread crumbs in the `1column.phtml` file?

Comment: It's magento default one it automatically come did u remove any where

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `1column.phtml` file please check below code

```
        <div class="main">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') // for breadcrumbs ?> 
            <div class="col-main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```